# Cannot understand an answer to an algorithm

Tags: algorithm

I was doing this question today.

Basically, question asks for the largest 'Decent' Number having N digits where 'Decent' number is:

1. Only 3 and 5 as its digits.
2. Number of times 3 appears is divisible by 5.
3. Number of times 5 appears is divisible by 3.

Input Format

> The 1st line will contain an integer T, the number of test cases,
>   followed by T lines, each line containing an integer N i.e. the number
>   of digits in the number

Output Format

> Largest Decent number having N digits. If no such number exists, tell
>   Sherlock that he is wrong and print '-1'

Sample Input

```
4
1
3
5
11
```

Sample Output

```
-1
555
33333
55555533333
```

Explanation

> For N=1 , there is no such number.  For N=3, 555 is only possible
>   number. For N=5, 33333 is only possible number. For N=11 , 55555533333
>   and all of permutations of digits are valid numbers, among them, the
>   given number is the largest one.

I've solved it using normal method but saw this answer:

```
t = int(raw_input())

for _ in range(t):
    n = int(raw_input())
    c3 = 5*(2*n%3)
    if c3 > n:
        print -1
    else:
        print '5' * (n-c3) + '3'*c3
```

Can anyone explain the method please? Especially the line 'c3 = 5*(2*n%3)', thanks

Comment: Your link is broken, and it's unclear what the question is without it. Please post the full question, and what this program is supposed to be doing. Why is it asking for input? What are the valid ranges of input?

Comment: See: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/43709/sherlock-and-the-beast

Comment: The link doesn't help. I'm not looking for the answer to this question. I couldn't understand this particular solution using 'c3 = 5*(2*n%3)' line, which seem like a math rule or so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We are looking for integer solutions of n = 5*x + 3*y where 5*x is the number of 3s and 3*y is the number of 5s. Both x and y must be >= 0 and x should be as small as possible since we can build larger numbers if we have more 5s.

Transforming this gives y = (n-5*x)/3. In order for y to be an integer n-5*x must be a multiple of 3 so we can calculate modulo 3 (I write == for is congruent modulo 3 from now on).

n-5*x == 0

n == 5*x == 2*x (because 5 == 2)

multiplying both sides by 2 gives

2*n == 4*x == x (because 4 == 1)

Since we want x small we take x = 2 * n % 3 and y = (n-5*x)/3

There is no solution if y < 0.